# Can AD Data Connector API calls impact other currently executing APIs?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Can AD Data Connector API calls impact other currently executing APIs?
The existing projects will remain in 360 and only new projects will utilize ACC.

Here is our potential scenario:

- ACC will be using the DC API approach
- 360 API pipeline continues in tandem with ACC API based on amount of work to transition dashboard/reports

Does anyone have any experience or information?
Will this cause resource issues like throttling, data locking, etc. OR are they actually two different data capture streams and will Not impact each other?

Searched on AD but didn't see any specific information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The question is not clear to me.  What is AD?  By Data Connector, are you talking about this API?  
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/data-connector-requests-POST/
Generally, REST API is stateless. Rate limit is per each endpoints. in case of Data Connector API, it is written here: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/rate-limits/data-connector-rate-limits/

Comment: AD stands for Autodesk
Yes we currently have API's running for BIM360
If we implement Data Connector API then it could potentially impact the currently running API's. That is in the form of trying to collect DATA e.g.
BIM360 Issues API is executing and extracting DATA
Data Connector API is executing and extracting DATA for Issues

They are both trying to capture the same DATA. So the question is more about how Data Connector DATA capture could impact BIM360 DATA capture

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Terry, and sorry for the late reply. I missed the update.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the Data Connector product team. They confirm that
there is no impact if you are using issues API and data connector API at the same time to extract the same data. They are hitting two different back ends. (We cannot expose the architecture. We can assure them there is no impact).

That said, there was a question of if you really need to pull the same data twice? If it is a bi-directional integration then definitely the service API is the way to go. If the use case is to get data for analytics and BI purposes then we should recommend Data Connector. There might be two workflows mentioned above. Maybe you are polling Issues data as there is not webhooks support with Issues API currently.

Anyway, I hope this clarify your concern in original post.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation
we have an existing single direction Issues API running for BIM360
we hope to eventually migrate bim360 to use DC as well as ACC
but that will take more effort and planned for our phase 2 plan.

Comment: I see. During transition period - that makes sense.